# is ID column required in my DB table?

Tags: mysql

In my database, I have a table "user" which has user information, such as "id", "user_name", "email" and some other data. I have another table "photos" which has "id", "user_name", "photo_id". The "id" in both tables is an auto increment integer, and primary key. 
I select the photo_id from photos table, by a specific user_name, therefore I think that there is no need to have "id" in the photos table. Is it correct?
If there is no need to have "id" column in photos table, then what should be the primary key?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but generally the setup is  UserId, Username, Email  and UserId, PhotoId  if what you have is a cross reference table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered what would happen if you changed the user name for some reason?  Using IDs to key tables means you can change the content as needed without having to repoint things (manually or via update triggers).

Answer (score 0):

It's my philosophy that you should always have an Id field in a table. You never know when you might have to add on and reference that id for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that `photo_id` and `id` are essentially the same thing. Seeing as the `id` is the auto increment integer (And you should have set UNIQUE too) get rid of `photo_id`

In addition, you should use the `user_id` as opposed to the name, otherwise two users with the same name will get eachothers pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Generally is a good idea to use ids that are not related to the business objects, that way the objects in the future can change and that wont have a major impact in the structure of your database.